# question mark with diamond causing invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00 in postgres in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, redis, pg, ioredis

I am using `postgres` as `DB` with `pg` npm module along with `nodejs`.
I am getting values from using ioredis from this command

```
let value = await redis.lrange('key', 0 ,-1 )
```

one of the value in list is following which is casuing above mentioned issue

```
"{\"user_output_coding\":[\"\\nAman\\n\\n\",\"\\nxK\\u001d*\xef\xbf\xbd\\n\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\nbhjs\\n\\n\",\"\\ndfgghgf\\ndese\\nrreteyt\\n\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\nghjhff\\ntyuyytu\\n\\n\",\"\\nbebzbh\\nasdf\\nasdf\\n\\n\",\"\\nfdgfdfgdfg\\ntrtyertgtrrgthtrt\\n\"]}"
```

Then I used `value = JSON.parse( value)` which converts this string into the following one

```
value = { "user_output_coding" : [ "\nAman\n\n","\nxK\u001d*�\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\nbhjs\n\n","\ndfgghgf\ndese\nrreteyt\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\nghjhff\ntyuyytu\n\n","\nbebzbh\nasdf\nasdf\n\n","\nfdgfdfgdfg\ntrtyertgtrrgthtrt\n"]}
```

I am using postgres as my database and want to store this array of string `user_output_coding`.
Postgres column is :

```
  user_output text[] default '{}'
```

But it gives me error

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00                                        
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/codequotient/CQ_Main_Server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)            
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/codequotient/CQ_Main_Server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)                 
    at Parser.parse (/home/codequotient/CQ_Main_Server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)                         
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/codequotient/CQ_Main_Server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)                    
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

I think this error is due to the presence of some invalid character. i have tried using pg utils like this so that its internal module could sanitize this array of string

```
const postgreUtil = require('pg/lib/utils');
postgreUtil.prepareValue( value );
```

But still no success.

Please suggest a generic solution to save this in postgres successfully.

Comment: Are you sure `'xK\u001d*�\n'` is meant to be a string and not a byte sequence? `�` might usually indicate an unmatched UTF-16 surrogate byte pair; these shouldn’t be in strings.

Comment: what's the first string supposed to be?

Comment: @SebastianSimon user is sending his code for compilation and i am saving his output ini DB. How can i solve this becuase user can print anything

Comment: @Thomas use can print anything, i need to sanitize this so that i can store it properly in postgres

Comment: This as a [valid Unicode character](https://unicodeplus.com/U+FFFD). If the user can put any string in there, how do you know that this character is not supposed to be there? And if it is not supposed to be there, what is supposed to be there instead?

Comment: @Thomas  i got your point but then why am i getting error in first place. I thought this error might be due to these unusual characters like \u001d and �.

Comment: @Thomas i have updated my question so that you can understand my case better

Comment: This has nothing to do with UTF-8 or the "weird" characters, Postgres seems to have a problem with null-bytes in strings: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/626803.19538.qm@web59808.mail.ac4.yahoo.com and that for over a decade now.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas add it as answer and so I can mark it right answer and share how can I remove those null characters from string